# Understanding the RATIO constants in TCPDF

Tags: pdf, svg, tcpdf

I am using a letter size page with TCPDF and inserting SVG images into it. In the tcpdf_config.php file I set

```
define ('PDF_UNIT', 'in');
```

However, I am having trouble understanding what the following constants do:

```
define ('PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO', 1.25);

define('K_CELL_HEIGHT_RATIO', 1.25);
```

I understand that the first one adjusts the conversion between pixels and user units (inches in my case), but how do I know what the ratio should actually be? Does the 72dpi also come into play when calculating this value?

Comment: Thanks for this question I'm having the same issue.  I want my design to be pixel (cm/mm) perfect.  How can we achieve this outcome?  Did you ever find out?

Comment: No, unfortunately I never did find an answer to this. Thanks for upvoting though, hopefully someone has an answer. :)